# Detailed balance distribution reflecting a random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

[image]

This above example happens in an infinite state space $S = {i}_{i=1}$

By the definition of detailed balance condition,

> Definition: 
>   $\pi\left ( x \right )p\left ( x,y \right ) = \pi\left ( y \right )p\left ( y,x \right )$

The author asserts that the initial distribution given in the example satisfies the detailed balance condition but this is not clear and when I try to attempt, I was unable to show this is true.

Secondly, there is an exponent $i$ in the explicit form for $\pi$; where does this exponent come from?

Comment: Is there no one who knows? The stochastic/ markov tag seems to be very slow moving...

Comment: What initial distribution are you talking about? The author says that the chain is a birth-death process and thus will satisfy the detailed balance equations. Also, it's been only 3 hours since you asked the question. You must have more patience than that.

Comment: @Greenparker That explains. 
May I know why the exponent i exists?

Comment: Welcome to CV @Physkid Sometimes good questions can literally take months or years to receive good answers on this site. Please have patience. :)

Comment: @Alexis Thank you for telling me that. I was under the impression that the question was "unanswerable" due certain constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have established that since this is an irreducible positive-recurrent birth-death process, it [satisfies a detailed balance condition for a (unique) stationary distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199657/countable-state-markov-chain-detailed-balance-consequences).

Thus for all states $i, j$, $\pi(i) P(i,j) = \pi(j) P(j,i)$, where $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution of this process defined for all $i \geq 0$.

For $j = i+1$, $i \geq 0$  we have that
\begin{align*}
\pi(i) P(i,i+1) &= \pi(i+1) P(i+1,i) \\
\Rightarrow p \pi(i) &= (1-p)\pi(i+1) \\
\Rightarrow \pi(i+1) & = \pi(i) \left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)\,.
\end{align*}

This is what they do in the example. But note that $i$ is chosen generically, so this holds for all $i \geq 0$. That is,
\begin{align*}
\pi(i) & = \pi(i-1) \left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)\\
& = \pi(i-2) \left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)^2 \\
& =\pi(i-3) \left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)^3\\
& \vdots\\
& = \pi(0)  \left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)^i\\
& =  c\left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)^i\,.
\end{align*}
So the exponent $i$ comes from an iterative argument.

Comment: Very clear now!